# What does "#" mean before a macro?

Tags: c

I need some explanation on this code

```
#define TRACE_PRINT5 (F, X)   fprintf(stderr, "%s" STRGY(__LINE__) ":(" #X "): ", X);
```

I know what does # on beginning, but I don't understand what does on `":(" #X"): "`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called ["stringizing"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html); When you add `#`, the macro will treat the argument like a string (e.g. getting the name of the thing passed in, instead of the value.)

So for example, if you write:

```
const char* someString = "abc";
TRACE_PRINT5(something, someString); // let's assume this is on line 10 for __LINE__
```

That should expand to:

```
const char* someString = "abc";
fprintf(stderr, "%s" "10" ":(" "someString" "): ", "abc");
```

(Assuming the `STRGY` macro just converts its argument to a string.)

Answer (score 2):

When you put `#` before something in a macro it gets the value as string literal.

In your case takes `X` as a string literal.
This means that if you pass the variable `age` with type `int` it will pass put "age" on the place of `#X`